# How to run history command('!') in shell script?

Tags: shell

I made script like below.

```
history
read input
!$input
```

But that makes the error:

> ./history.sh: line 8: !2185: command not found

How to run '!' command in shell script?

Comment: What is `!$input` supposed to be doing? Executing `read` command again?

Comment: @anubhava I wanna re-running command no.xxxx (<- input) like '!2185'.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should need something like:

```
history
echo $!
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script you can use `fc` shell builtin for this.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# enable history
set -o history

# example command
ls -lrt

echo "now run ls from history..."
fc -s ls
```

to re-execute most recent `ls` from history.